# App server requests are in cancelling state in Marklogic for long time

Tags: marklogic

Some of the queries are in cancelling sate in the Marklogic app server for a long time those queries are not disappeared showing in cancelling state in-app server. Can anyone help us to why those queries are in cancelling state?

Comment: There could be a variety of reasons. Usually it's the result of a large and long-running transaction that has timed out or hit some error, but it could have also been explicitly cancelled with `xdmp:request-cancel()` or by clicking links on Admin UI. If there is a lot of work that had been done, it could take time to cancel. How long is "a long time"? You may want to open a Support ticket with MarkLogic and provide logs to get detailed analysis of an issue, especially if those cancelled queries don't cancel and appear "stuck".

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes, Those queries are long-running queries and cancelled by Marklogic with a time-out message in the log, Those queries are more than 40Hrs in the cancelling state. I will raise the request in ML support. Thaks for info